# JPlayer не проигрывает трек

Tags: jquery, mp3

Проблема вот в чем:
Подключаю в jPlayer треки со своего сервера (указывая полный путь а-ля http://domain.ru/track.mp3) и все работает отлично! Но, когда подключаю треки с другого сервера, на firefox в firebug-консоли выскакивает такая ошибка:

> HTTP "Content-Type" of "application/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource %path_to_track%.mp3

Интересно то, что когда я перекачиваю этот трек на сервер, то он нормально проигрывается!
В иных от огнелиса браузерах ошибка не замечается. В чем может быть проблема? Заранее вас благодарю!

Comment: Никогда не подумал бы, но проблема была в самом jplayer'е. У него были указаны не все mime-типы, я добавил application/mpeg в тип mp3 и все заработало.
Сергею спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Огнелис не имеет встроенной поддержки mp3, поэтому jPlayer должен подгружать свой .swf плеер. Проверьте параметр swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/", в скрипте.

Comment: Сейчас проверил, дописал, но ничего не изменилось. Как проверить, подключился ли swf?

Comment: и да, еще раз повторюсь — те файлы, что уже лежат на сервере проигрываются нормально, а на удаленном сервере — нет :с

Comment: > Как проверить, подключился ли swf? 

Просто откройте его по этому адресу, или посмотрите в ресурсах.

Может, он пытается открыть его на удаленном сервере?

Comment: swfPath "/js/jplayer.swf"
Такой путь в firebug'е

Comment: да, и этот файл реально есть и точно такое же подключение на страницах, где нормально работает